# jquery selector index changes with greasemonkey

Tags: jquery, greasemonkey

This is a subsequent question from the one I deleted because I thought I solved the issue. But now I'm 100% sure it's from greasemonkey.

code below

```
$("head>link:nth-child(4)").after('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="...">');
```

What actually happens, is that instead of selecting the 4th child of  (which is a link tag), it selects the 3rd child and puts the content after it, instead of after the 4th element.

My workaround is just adding +1 to the index, as follows

```
$("head>link:nth-child(5)").after('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="...">');
```

I don't add a @require jquery-file-url because I'm executing the script on a page with a  tag already calling it.

Can someone verify this with greasemonkey please?

Why does it happen and if this is the actual case for greasemonkey scripts, should I be expecting more changes with code run on a greasemonkey userscript?

Answer (score 0):

The [`:nth-child()`](https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) selector is designed to start counting index from `1`.
I do not know if you was aware about this.

One think is for sure, Greasemonkey has nothing to do with your issue.

Greasemonkey does nothing else than executing the Javascript code you provide.

Comment: I've read the selector's documentation. But I'm currently executing a greasemonkey script on a webpage with the code above, and just like I explained in my post, I have to add +1 to the selector's index for it to behave as it should have. Instead of the 1st child being selected by (1), it can only be selected by (2). It only happens when I'm using greasemonkey. That's my issue.

Comment: @Corssa Maybe could you provide the exact Greasemonkey script (including the website) you are using? Greasemonkey **is** Javascript, it should work too. The only issue you may encounter is related to the moment when the script is executed.

Comment: Is it possible that adblock might be deleting a certain link tag in the moment the webpage opens, and therefore my $(selector) targets an unintended different tag? Does adblock run before a greasemonkey script is executed?

Comment: @Corssa It is indeed possible that Adblock or any other plugin / script delete one of the link tag from the page, which could explain the issue. But I do know if Adblock runs before Greasemonkey, try to disable it.